# set imageio compression level in python

Tags: python, animated-gif, python-imageio

I'm using imageio in Python to read in jpg images and write them as a gif, using something resembling the code below.

```py
import imageio

with imageio.get_writer('mygif.gif', mode='I') as writer:
    for filename in framefiles:    # iterate over names of jpg files I want to turn into gif frames
    frame = imageio.imread(filename)
    writer.append_data(frame)
```

I'm noticing that the image quality in the gifs I produce is quite poor; I suspect this is due to some form of compression. Is there a way to tell imageio not to use any compression? Or maybe a way to do this with opencv instead?

Comment: What happened when you tried reading the documentation? What happened when you tried putting, for example, `imageio gif quality` [into a search engine](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=imageio+gif+quality)? Why exactly do you expect it to be possible to create good quality gifs from jpg in the first place - have you seen this done? (Are you familiar with the gif format?) Why not use an actual video format? What problem are you actually trying to solve - why do you want an animated gif?

Comment: Googling, I mostly found results for imageio in Java, where there looks to be no simple way to adjust compression. I'm making a gif because I was asked for one, but I don't see why an avi or mp4 wouldn't also suffice. I don't know much about any of these formats.

Comment: I would use other modules or external tools for this - ie. module `ffmpeg-python` or directly program `ffmpeg`, module `wand` or directly program `imagemagick`

Comment: diging in source code I found that I can access some `GIFWriter` settings: `writer._writer.opt_quantizer` and `writer._writer.opt_palette_size` but I think main problem is that `gif` can display only `256 colors` so it has to emulate some colors using few dots with different collors. Other problem can make JPG files which could reduce image quality.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Real problem is that `GIF` can display only `256 colors` (8-bits color) so it has to reduce `24-bits` colors (RGB) to  `256 colors` or it has emulate more colors using dots with different colors - [ditherring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dither).

---

As for options:

Digging in source code I found that it can get two parameters `quantizer`, `palettesize` which can control image/animation quality. (There is also `subrectangles` to reduce file size)

But there are two plugins for `GIF` which use different modules `Pillow` or `FreeImage` and they need different value for `quantizer`

`PIL` needs integer `0`, `1` or `2`.

`FI` needs string `'wu'` or `'nq'` (but later it converts it to integer `0` or `1`)

They also keep these values in different way so if you want get current value or change it after `get_writer()` then you also need different code.

You can select module with `format='GIF-PIL'` or `format='GIF-FI'`

```
with imageio.get_writer('mygif.gif', format='GIF-PIL', mode='I', 
                        quantizer=2, palettesize=32) as writer:
    print(writer)
    #print(dir(writer))
    #print(writer._writer)
    #print(dir(writer._writer))

    print('quantizer:', writer._writer.opt_quantizer)
    print('palette_size:', writer._writer.opt_palette_size)

    #writer._writer.opt_quantizer = 1
    #writer._writer.opt_palette_size = 256
    #print('quantizer:', writer._writer.opt_quantizer)
    #print('palette_size:', writer._writer.opt_palette_size)


with imageio.get_writer('mygif.gif', format='GIF-FI', mode='I', 
                        quantizer='nq', palettesize=32) as writer:
    print(writer)
    #print(dir(writer))

    print('quantizer:', writer._quantizer)
    print('palette_size:', writer._palettesize)

    #writer._quantizer = 1
    #writer._palettesize = 256
    #print('quantizer:', writer._quantizer)
    #print('palette_size:', writer._palettesize)
```

I tried to create animations with different settings but they don't look much better.

I get better result using external program [ImageMagick](https://imagemagick.org/) in console/terminal

```
convert image*.jpg mygif.gif
```

but still it wasn't as good as video or static images.

You can run it in Python

```
os.system("convert image*.jpg mygif.gif")

subprocess.run("convert image*.jpg mygif.gif", shell=True)
```

Or you can try to do it with module [Wand](https://docs.wand-py.org/) which is a wrapper on `ImageMagick`

---

Source code: `GifWriter` in [pillowmulti.py](https://github.com/imageio/imageio/blob/master/imageio/plugins/pillowmulti.py#L123) and in [freeimagemulti.py](https://github.com/imageio/imageio/blob/master/imageio/plugins/freeimagemulti.py#L142)

```
* wu - Wu, Xiaolin, Efficient Statistical Computations for Optimal Color Quantization
* nq (neuqant) - Dekker A. H., Kohonen neural networks for optimal color quantization
```

---

Doc: [GIF-PIL Static and animated gif (Pillow)](https://imageio.readthedocs.io/en/stable/format_gif-pil.html#gif-pil), [GIF-FI Static and animated gif (FreeImage)](https://imageio.readthedocs.io/en/stable/format_gif-fi.html#gif-fi)